# Getting Error when using max_length form_validation

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm getting an error message with max_length[20] even though the field doesn't exceed 20

```
public function test()
{   

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname',      '<b>Firstname</b>',      'trim|required|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('middlename',     '<b>Middlename</b>',     'trim|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname',       '<b>Lastname/b>',        'trim|required|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email',          '<b>Email</b>',          'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('number',         '<b>Number</b>',         'trim|required|max_length[13]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username',       '<b>Username</b>',       'trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password',       '<b>Password</b>',       'trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type',           '<b>User Type</b>',      'trim|required|max_length[1]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status',         '<b>User Status</b>',    'trim|required|max_length[1]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('rfid',           '<b>RFID</b>',           'trim|required|max_length[15]|xss_clean');



        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

           $data = array('status'=>false, 'data'=>validation_errors());
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

password only have 6 characters that is sent to my back-end using jquery ajax and I'm getting:

> The Password field cannot exceed 20 characters in length.

where could my code go wrong?

Comment: what happens if you send 6 characters in `rfid` field? getting the same error?

Comment: Post your view. Validation part not helping that much.

Comment: @jagad89 I'm using jquery ajax on passing data to back-end

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST)` and add output to your question

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana it validates chronologically, and as it is Its still on Password field .. maybe they will have the same error as they have the same rules..

Comment: @Warren Post your html and ajax code too.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, figured out that password was indeed exceeding 20 chars

Comment: not entirely related to your issue, but take this a question-intended-to-be-a-suggestion: What would be a valid reason to limit the length of a password? You're basically forcing your users into using less secure passwords than those they might be willing to use (plus, you're making it easier for a brute force attack to succeed as you're telling a potential attacker that he need not try anything longer than 20, thus helping him craft a more efficient attack)